# Props name getting converted as object key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a data response of form:

```
claim_amount_arr: [218691.44]
claim_approval_status: ["In Process"]
percentages_claim: [1]
percentages_claim_amount: [1]
total_claim_arr: [2]
_id: 0
__proto__: Object
```

I want to convert it to array so as to map it into table further in a component. Since it does not have a key, I am not able to access it's key value pair for mapping. 
I tried the following approach but then it eliminates all the key from the array:

```
const summary_props = this.props.summary
    //console.log(summary_props); //this console gives me data as shown in image above

    const sortedvalue = Object.keys(summary_props).map(key => {
        return summary_props[key];
    });

    console.log(sortedvalue);
```

output of this console: 
[image]

Please help.

Comment: How have you implemented your form? Please share that implementation too.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I have edited the question. Please take a look

Comment: do you want each property do be an element of array in form of object, like: `{a:1, b:2}` to become `[{a:1},{b:2}]`?

Comment: Please post the expected output to the question. Also, post the input in a JSON format to the question. We cannot copy screenshots to create an answer.

Comment: @adiga I need to map this object output into a table, but for that it needs to converted into array, which  I am not able to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Try [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).
In short, it can transform an object into an array.

**Edit**: More specific here

```js
Object.entries(formData).map(([key, value]) => {
  //Now you can access both the key and their value
})
```

Comment: Object.entries convert array out of every object [key:value] pair. How do I then map/iterate the data obtained using this approach?

Comment: You would use the map function, where is parameter if is an entry. An entry is an array, where the first item is the key and the second is the value.

Comment: @bubble-cord I did edit the code. Note that `Object.entries()` is not available for ES6, so Babel is needed.

Answer (score 0):

`class ClaimInformation()
{
     constructor(data,index)
     {
         this.claim_amount  =  data.claim_amount_arr[index];
         this.claim_approval_status = data.claim_approval_status[index];
         this.percentage_claim = data.percentage_claim[index];
         this.percentages_claim_amount = data.percentages_claim_amount[index];
         this.total_claim = data.total_claim_arr[index];
     }
}`

`var claims = [];
for(let i = 0; i < response.claim_amount_arr.length; i++){
    claims.push(new ClaimInformation(response,i));
}`